# Numeric to DateTime format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I would like to know what is the best way to convert `201509122150` (numeric) to `Date` class within `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` format.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
x <- 201509122150 
as.POSIXct(as.character(x), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")
# [1] "2015-09-12 21:50:00 CEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hm(x)
#[1] "2015-09-12 21:50:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
x <- 201509122150
```